# Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined in Util.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a piece of code that I use to include all the javascript library files that is needed:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/layout.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/search.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/lib/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/lib/jquery-ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/jquery-ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/lib/util/Util.js"></script>
```

This fails on the first line of Util.js which:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
```

with a define is not defined error.
Is there a file I have missed that is a prerequisite of Util.js?

Comment: What is Util.js? Can you link to the documentation?

Comment: @ADASein are you confusing the reference to jQuery-ui as a second reference to jQuery?

Comment: @ADASein I suppose, but the issue here is that `Util.js` is an AMD/Common module and OP doesn't appear to be using Require or any other module loader. The docs should indicate which one Util is wrapped for.

Comment: Is there a way to track which version of jquery, Util.js is wrapped for? I do not have a read me or doc associated with it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery; it probably wants to be loaded with [Require](http://requirejs.org/)